# How to print to web browser's developer console

Tags: python, web, flask

I currently have a flask project deployed on IIS 11 using FastCGI and I was wondering if there is a way for me to print to the web console within the flask app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on when you need to print the message to the console. If it's live messaging like notifications / updates as they happen you'd need a websocket that creates an event on the Flask side that is picked up by Websockets on the javascript side that calls a `console.log()`

If it's a 1 time message once the page loads, just feed the message to the `render_template()` funciton:

```
render_template('index.html', message=message)
```

You will then have that available in the template and then you can `console.log(message)` from the client side

Comment: Good idea I will try this out. I was thinking something similar with the live messages and the websockets, I have done something similar in the past.

Comment: However, would it be possible to feed the python runtime errors to the console using the websocket method?

Comment: @ryan_thomp Im thinking a custom event for errors. On javascript side "socketio.on('error', function(data){console.log(data)})". On flask side have your try/except blocks emit a message on the except: "except Exception as e: socketio.emit('error', {'error': e})"

Comment: I did what you said however I see nothing within the developer console. Would you like me to make an edit to my main post to see what I did wrong

Comment: @ryan_thomp that works! I'll take a look once changed

Comment: i got it working. I had the return render_template in the wrong spot causing it to mess up  Thank You